# How to fix an animation causing high CLS Google Page Speed number

Tags: html, css, pagespeed

I have this animation in my website and works fine.
The problem is that when I check my site on pagespeed it seems they don't like this effect.

```css
.contBachecaHiGift {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 36px;
    color: #c03022;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.contBachecaHiGift .dynamic-text {
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 36px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    font-weight: 700;
}

ul>li, ol>li {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.contBachecaHiGift .dynamic-text .item {
    position: relative;

    -webkit-animation: move 15s linear 0s infinite;
    animation: move 15s linear 0s infinite;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}



@-webkit-keyframes moveHP {
  0% {-webkit-transform: translate(700px,0);}
  100% {-webkit-transform: translate(-1200px,0);}
}
@keyframes moveHP {
  0% {-webkit-transform: translate(700px,0);}
  100% {-webkit-transform: translate(-1200px,0);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes move{
  0% {top: 2px;}
  10% {top: 2px;}
  20% {top: -30px;}
  30% {top: -30px;}
  40% {top: -30px;}
  50% {top: 2px;}
  60% {top: 2px;}
  70% {top: 2px;}
  80% {top: -30px;}
  90% {top: -30px;}
  100% {top: 2px;}
 }
@keyframes move{
  0% {top: 2px;}
  10% {top: 2px;}
  20% {top: -30px;}
  30% {top: -30px;}
  40% {top: -30px;}
  50% {top: 2px;}
  60% {top: 2px;}
  70% {top: 2px;}
  80% {top: -30px;}
  90% {top: -30px;}
  100% {top: 2px;}
}
```

```html
<div class="text-container contBachecaHiGift">
  <ul class="dynamic-text">
    <!-- TESTO PER LE PROMO -->
    <li class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor</li>
    <li class="item">incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris</li>
    <li class="item">nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

How can I fix for CLS?
How can I put it horizontally?

Comment: What is a CLS?  Where are you checking your site at and what specifically is it saying when they "don't like" the effect?

Comment: Sorry man, i dont' explain very well. CLS is "Cumulative Layout Shift" of pagespeed of Google

Comment: @FiniteLooper CLS is Content Layout Shift. Google's page speed will show that content is shifting on load - usually happens when a hero image loads in (without an initial height set) and pushes content down the page. Jackom, I would not worry about this since it's the effect you want - and CLS is only a problem if you are loading in large assets that are causing slow downs for users.

Comment: @Jackom tagging so you see this. You may be able to appease the page speed algorithm if you set a delay on the text animation. Essentially, don't start until the page is loaded. You could do this two ways: use the animation-delay property of your `animation: move 15s linear 0s infinite;` to something like `5s` OR use JS to wait until the window is loaded, and add a class to your `dynamic-text` that will trigger the animation to start. As stated early, this really isn't that big of an issue.

Comment: OK, makes sense now.  yeah I don't think this is an issue.  You aren't doing anything crazy here, just moving an element up and down.  FYI, in your CSS you can combine keyframes like you combine element selectors:  `20%,30%,40% {top: -30px;}`